# unindex elasticsearch element with a deleted_at not empty

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-artisan

I'm looking to remove element with a deleted_at field not empty from the search area of my application.

The product unindex properly because if I try to display it a 404 is return. But what I don't understand is why it keep showing up in the results when a search that concerne him is done.

The reset happening like this

```php
foreach($indexes as $key=>$index)
{
    if(Elasticsearch::indices()->exists(['index'=>$key]))
    {
       $this->warn('reset index: '.$key);
       Elasticsearch::indices()->delete(['index'=>$key]
    }
}
```

Im guessing this has to do with `'soft_delete' => false,` from scout.php but I don't know what to do with that.

The item shall be visible on the database but invisible to the users, he is visible in result research for the moment and the user have a 404 if he try to display it, which is good but I don't want him to find it on the first place.

Comment: Can you post some code and elaborate further on the issue. Its not clear.

Comment: There I edit, hope you can understand my problem